# How to calculate monthly payment of a loan

Tags: loans, calculation, interest

I am trying to solve this question:
Your brother-in-law asks you to lend him $100,000 as a second mortgage on his vacation
home. He promises to make level monthly payments for 10 years, 120 payments in all.
You decide that a fair interest rate is 8% compounded annually. What should the
monthly payment be on the $100,000 loan?

The solution given is 1198.58

[image]

But if I use this formula I got 1213.28 instead

[image]

Can someone help me to understand how to calcualte the monthly payment in this case and why we can't use the second formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is how you interpret "8% compounded annually" In reality, loan rates are quoted as "annual", meaning the actual monthly interest rate is n/12 (`r/n` in your formula). Most loan payment formulas (including the one you used) make this assumption.

When instead you say "compounded annually", you need to find the monthly rate that corresponds to 8% annually when you apply it to a monthly payment (compounding it 12 times).  So the difference is a monthly rate of 0.6434% versus 0.66667%

Answer (score 2):

As D Stanley comments, the problem is with the rate.

"8% compounded annually" is a 'nominal' rate, as identified by the statement of a compounding period.

A 'nominal rate compounded annually' is exactly the same as an effective annual rate.  However, to obtain a nominal annual rate *compounded monthly* ( *i* ) from an effective annual rate ( *r* ) . . .

[image: i]

as is described on Wikipedia: [Effective interest rate calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).

```
i.e. with  r = 0.08 effective annual rate
           n = 12
           i = n ((1 + r)^(1/n) - 1) = 0.0772084 compounded monthly
```

What does this mean?  The expression `(1 + r)^(1/n) - 1` is the interest *per month* ( = 0.6434%), calculated from the annual effective rate.  And this is simply multiplied by 12 to obtain the 'nominal rate compounded monthly'.  It is defined like this so that given a 'nominal rate compounded monthly' the monthly interest can be obtained by simple division by 12.  Handy for the days before pocket calculators, as described here: [2008 Federal Reserve memo](https://www.federalreserve.gov/SECRS/2008/July/20080708/R-1314/R-1314_10005_1.pdf), i.e. "the true calculation [involving inverse powers] ... was not readily available".

Using this converted rate ( *ì* ) the payment calculation can be completed.

```
P = 100000
t = 10
```

[image: eq]